# how to use ul and li in code behind c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to fill `li` and `ul` of an HTML file using my database.
single category representing multiple items in database.

I have taken the `li` items in a string, I am replacing [food] with `CATEGORY` name and [itemTemplate] with `ITEMS`. The issue in my code is the category name is repeating 
Every time as new item display. I have to show category name once and add all related items within that category.

```
String liTemplate = "<li><h4 class='menu-title-section'> <h4 class='menu-title-section'><a href='#appetizers'>[food]</a></h4>[itemTemplate]</li>";
String itemTemplate = "SOME ITEM TEMPLETE";

DataTable dt = dm.GetData("spTestMenu")

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<ul class='our-menu'>");
String liTemplateWorkingCopy = String.Empty, itemTemplateWorkingCopy = String.Empty

foreach (DataRow level1DataRow in dt.Rows)
{
    liTemplateWorkingCopy = liTemplate;
    itemTemplateWorkingCopy = itemTemplate;
    SubCategoryName = level1DataRow["MealSubCatName"].ToString();

    if (!previusSubCat.Equals(SubCategoryName))
    {
        liTemplateWorkingCopy = liTemplateWorkingCopy.Replace("[food]", level1DataRow["MealSubCatName"].ToString());
        previusSubCat = SubCategoryName;
    }

    itemTemplateWorkingCopy = itemTemplateWorkingCopy.Replace("[foodtitle]", level1DataRow["itemName"].ToString());
    itemTemplateWorkingCopy = itemTemplateWorkingCopy.Replace("[imgsrc]", level1DataRow["imageURL"].ToString());
    itemTemplateWorkingCopy = itemTemplateWorkingCopy.Replace("[price]", level1DataRow["Price"].ToString());

    liTemplateWorkingCopy = liTemplateWorkingCopy.Replace("[itemTemplate]", itemTemplateWorkingCopy);
    sb.Append(liTemplateWorkingCopy);
    foodMenu.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Watch out - that looks like it could suffer from script injection; if you are going to build html manually, make sure to html-escape anything that is data

Comment: would it not be possible to just using the repeater control to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? There are probably way more elegant ways of doing this... If possible, you should avoid putting HTML in your code-behind.

Comment: So, was any of the answers helpfull? Did you manage to solve this issue? Please update this SO item...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `runat="server"` for `<li>` or `<ul>`..

```
<li class="abc" runat="server" id="first"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a ListView control for this. This way you can maintain the HTML outside of your code; it's cleaner that way and much more elegant.

Group your rows by the 'MealSubCatName' column, and use LINQ to create an anonymous object:

**C#**

```
var grouped = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(c => c["MealSubCatName"].ToString())
    .Select(g => new
    {
        category = g.FirstOrDefault()["MealSubCatName"].ToString(),
        items = g.Select(r => new { 
            title = r["itemName"].ToString(), 
            image = r["imageURL"].ToString() 
        })
    });
lvFood.DataSource = grouped;
lvFood.DataBind();
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvFood" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceholder" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <h4 class="menu-title-section">
                <a href="#appetizers"><%# Eval("category") %></a>
            </h4>
        </li>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("items") %>'>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src="<%# Eval("image")%>" alt="<%# Eval("title")%>" />
                <strong><%# Eval("title")%></strong><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add a div with runat server and assign a Id to that div and do something like this I did this trick here www.journeycook.com Check menu of this website.

Suppose you have a div with id link and runat server in ul tag

```
<ul>
<div runat="server" id="link">

</div>

</ul>
```

Now add c# code for fetch data using **SqlDataReader** class and using while loop do something like this

```
link.innerhtml+="<li>dr["yourcolumn"].ToString()</li>";
```

I hope it will give you some help

Comment: this produces invalid HTML; a div should not be a child of a ul

Comment: a <ul> may only contain <li>, so I guess you should use a <li> for this

Comment: but i am binding li dynamically here can i use ul as server tag in place of div here? @ReinderWit

Comment: You can make the UL into a HtmlGenericControl if you put an ID and runat="server" in there, yes